# Recorrer areglos dinamicamente Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, bucle-for, bucles

tengo un problema recorriendo 2 arreglos.
El problema es que necesito recorrer 2 arreglos dinamicamente, ya que los valores van a cambiar de acuerdo al proceso que se use.

Mi código;

```js
 let headers = ["Orden", "Contrapartida", "Nombre", "Valor env.", 
                "No. referencia", "Forma pago","Fecha de Depósito"]
                
          // val es un arreglo de objetos json
            let val = [
       {
          "Contrapartida": "llgfhfg",
          "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
          "Forma pago:": "FE",
          "No. referencia": 10645124,
          "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
          "Orden": 1,
          "Valor env.": 4.22
      },
      {
        "Contrapartida": "L00387041",
        "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
        "Forma pago:": "FE",
        "No. referencia": 14421691,
        "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
        "Orden": 2,
       "Valor env.": 26.22
      }
            ]
    
              //Comienzan los bucles
                 for (let k = 0; k < val.length; k++) {
                     for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                        // No Funciona
                        console.log("resultado", val[k].headers[i]) 
                        // Si Funciona
                        console.log("resultado", val[k].Orden) //

                        }
                        }
              // pero me da este error:
              // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
              // headers[i] lo puse para iterar todos los valores del headers               // que son las propiedades del 
              // Objeto Json y evitar poner esto:
              // val[k].Orden
              // val[k].Contrapartida
              // val[k].Nombre
```

Me podrían ayudar diciendo cual es el error o que alternativa puedo usar, ya que necesito recorrer estos arreglos dinámicamente y no quemar las propiedades del json, ya que como es dinámico las propiedades siempre van a cambiar

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner la estructura del arreglo como texto y no como imagen, solo así podemos probar para ver lo que está pasando. También corrige la asignación de `val`, porque termina en `.` y parece que algo le falta. Después de la asignación agrega `console.log(val);` y pon el resultado al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Debes utilizar reflection de javascript, javascript es reflexivo, por lo cual puedes acceder a los atributos de sus propiedades y dependiendo estas verlo como arreglo, mira en este video explico entries de javascript, espero te sirva. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWieb1nHOTc

Comment: gracias, ya corregí y puse la estructura json

Comment: El que no te funciona se debe a que estas tratando de acceder a una propiedad llamada headers dentro de cada objecto del arreglo val, pero headers no existe como propiedad por eso te lanza un error, porque no encuentra nada

Comment: Creo que lo que intenta hacer, es llamar a la propiedad que tiene algún nombre especificado en el arreglo `headers`. En tal caso, debería acceder a dicha propiedad asi: `val[k][headers[i]]`

SI este es el caso, podrías confirmarlo para elaborar una respuesta completa más una recomendación para evitar este tipo de errores en el futuro.

Comment: gracias por responder, efectivamente con val[k][headers[i]], pude resolver mi problema

Answer (score -2, accepted):

***Con val[k][headers[i]] puede arreglar mi problema.***

```js
let headers = ["Orden", "Contrapartida", "Nombre", "Valor env.", 
                "No. referencia", "Forma pago","Fecha de Depósito"]
                
          // val es un arreglo de objetos json
            let val = [
       {
          "Contrapartida": "llgfhfg",
          "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
          "Forma pago:": "FE",
          "No. referencia": 10645124,
          "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
          "Orden": 1,
          "Valor env.": 4.22
      },
      {
        "Contrapartida": "L00387041",
        "Fecha de Depósito": 44040,
        "Forma pago:": "FE",
        "No. referencia": 14421691,
        "Nombre": "ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO",
        "Orden": 2,
       "Valor env.": 26.22
      }
            ]
    
              //Comienzan los bucles
                 for (let k = 0; k < val.length; k++) {
                     for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                        console.log("resultado", val[k][headers[i]]) //
                        }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Para hacer obtener el valor de manera dinámica, JavaScript permite cargar el nombre de las claves como **String** usando los símbolos `[ ]` en lugar de hacer un llamada como miembro del objeto (`objeto.miembro`). De esta forma, para obtener el valor según los textos definidos en `headers` se puede hacer con:

```javascript
val[k][headers[i]]
```

## Recomendación

Si bien el código indicado soluciona el problema de la llamada, existe una forma "moderna" de ejecutar las mismas funcionalidades:

```javascript
const headers = [
  'Orden',
  'Contrapartida',
  'Nombre',
  'Valor env.',    
  'No. referencia',
  'Forma pago',
  'Fecha de Depósito'
];
                
const val = [
  {
    'Contrapartida': 'llgfhfg',
    'Fecha de Depósito': 44040,
    'Forma pago:': 'FE',
    'No. referencia': 10645124,
    'Nombre': 'ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO',
    'Orden': 1,
    'Valor env.': 4.22
  },
  {
    'Contrapartida': 'L00387041',
    'Fecha de Depósito': 44040,
    'Forma pago:': 'FE',
    'No. referencia': 14421691,
    'Nombre': 'ESPIN SANDOVAL DIEGO MAURICIO',
    'Orden': 2,
    'Valor env.': 26.22
  }
];

for (const v of val) { // Itera los objetos definidos en val
  for (const header of headers) { // Itera las claves definidas en headers
    console.log(v[header] ?? `"${header}" no es miembro de v`); // Llamada a la propiedad con un nombre esperado definiendo una respuesta por defecto
  }
}
```